# How to compare, match, and append multiple values in multiple CSV files?

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this, and I'm not sure how to `Import-Csv` with 2 different files through the same pipeline and export a value found...

So lets start with CSV file 1: I only want the values for `LoginNumber` where `Type = H and (ContractorDomain -ne $null -or ContractorDomain -ne "")`. For example, this should only pull values `0031482` and `2167312` from below.

**Note: I only added spaces and arrows to make it easier to read as columns here. The csv files have no spaces between the column values or arrows.**

```
"LoginNumber","Type","ContractorDomain"
"0031482"    ,"H"   ,"P12345"  <<
"1251632"    ,"P"   ,"A52671"
"2167312"    ,"H"   ,"425126"  <<
"0598217"    ,"L"   ,""
"1405735"    ,"H"   ,""
"2058194"    ,"A"   ,"L21514"
```

When the value number for `LoginNumber` (based on conditions explained above) is found, search for it in CSV file 2. Then grab the value of `AccountStatus` and `SamAccountName` for the respective value of `UserIDNumber`.

```
"SamAccountName","UserIDNumber","AccountDescriptionDetails","AccountStatus"
"jd12395"       ,"0052142"     ,"Company CEO"              ,"Enabled"
"jwet"          ,"2167312"     ,"Software Developer"       ,"Disabled"  <<
"1b3gas5"       ,"1385293"     ,"Project Manager"          ,"Disabled"
"632g1fsa"      ,"0031482"     ,"QA Tester"                ,"Enabled"   <<
"4126hs"        ,"0000418"     ,"Program Manager"          ,"Disabled"
"axv"           ,"1840237"     ,"Accountant Administrator" ,"Disabled"
```

For the 3rd CSV file we have the following:

```
"domainName","SameAccountName","DateExpired"
"TempDomain","jwet"           ,"20151230"    <<
"PermDomain","p21942"         ,""
"PermDomain","qz231034"       ,""
"TempDomain","632g1fsa"       ,"20151231"    <<
"TempDomain","ru20da2bb22"    ,"20160425"
```

Next, for the 3rd file, I want to add the column to plug in the `Disabled` and `Enabled` values (or `User Match Not Found` value):

```
"domainName","SameAccountName","DateExpired","UserStatus"
"TempDomain","jwet"           ,"20151230"   ,"Disabled"               <<
"PermDomain","p21942"         ,""           ,"User Match Not Found"
"PermDomain","qz231034"       ,""           ,"User Match Not Found"
"TempDomain","632g1fsa"       ,"20151231"   ,"Enabled"                <<
"TempDomain","ru20da2bb22"    ,"20160425"   ,"User Match Not Found"
```

I learned how to import-csv and create new columns with something like this...

```
Import-Csv $file | Select-Object -Property *, @{Name="UserStatus";Expression={
  if ($true) {"fill value in here"}
}} | Export-Csv $newFile -NoType
```

So I'm thinking something like this. I'm just not sure how to search/find/pass multiple CSV files values through the pipeline.

Note: some of these CSV files have like 15 columns before and after the columns we are searching for. Also, some of the columns values have a comma, so I can't really rely on the `-Delimiter ,`. Also, some of the column values do not have `"` (if you were to open the CSV in txt format).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Columns containing commas shouldn't be an issue if the values are properly quoted (i.e. if the CSV is valid). `Import-Csv` will correctly import a record `42,"a,b",c` as three values `42`, `a,b` and `c`. If your CSV isn't well-formed: fix that first.

Fetch the login IDs from the first CSV file:

```
$logins = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\file1.csv' |
          Where-Object { $_.Type -eq 'H' -and $_.ContractorDomain } |
          Select-Object -Expand LoginNumber
```

You can simplify the `ContractorDomain` property check to just `$_.ContractorDomain`, because PowerShell interprets both an empty string and `$null` [as a boolean value `$false`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) in that context. The same would happen for other zero or empty values (0, 0.0, empty array, etc.), but that shouldn't be an issue in your scenario.

Next create a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) mapping account names to their respective status. Filter the imported second CSV by the list of IDs you created before, so the hashtable contains only relevant mappings.

```
$accountStatus = @{}
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\file2.csv' | Where-Object {
  $logins -contains $_.UserIDNumber
} | ForEach-Object {
  $accountStatus[$_.SamAccountName] = $_.AccountStatus
}
```

With that hashtable you can now add the `UserStatus` column to your third CSV:

```
(Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\file3.csv') |
  Select-Object -Property *, @{n='UserStatus';e={
    if ($accountStatus.ContainsKey($_.SameAccountName)) {
      $accountStatus[$_.SameAccountName]
    } else {
      'User Match Not Found'
    }
  }} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\file3.csv' -NoType
```

The parentheses around the `Import-Csv` statement ensure that the file is completely read and closed before `Export-Csv` starts writing to it. They're only required if you're writing the modified data back to the same file and can be omitted otherwise. The asterisk selects all imported columns, and the additional [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) adds the new column you want to include.

Comment: This looks really good. I've been up for 2 days working on the code previous for this, so first chance I get to test it (probably after a few hours of sleep) I'll mark your answer if it passes. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Tested and works great! Sorry it took me so long to respond. I had to redo the QuickAndDirty code I had 1 day to write to get to this point. I ended up just appending the information from file2 to file3, so now the search only needs to happen between file1 and file3. Reason for this is there are 18 different types of file2's, and no need to search through 18 files. So I had to modify the code a bit, but you explained it very well. Thank you so much :)