# Find Match and Add values in new column between 2 CSV files

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0

This is very similar to what I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234325/how-to-compare-match-and-append-multiple-values-in-multiple-csv-files), except there are only two files, and the searching is done in reverse.

## Explanation

Given the two files (`test1.csv` and `test2.csv` shown below), I need to match the `LoginNumber` from `test1.csv` with `UserIDNumber` from `test2.csv`.

Once the match is found, grab the value from column `ReportExpirationDate` in `test2.csv`.

If there is nothing in the value for `ReportExpirationDate`, the value should be changed from `$null` to `User Not Found`.

Finally, we need to append `test1.csv` with a column `ExpirationDateFromReport` while matching the `LoginNumber` and `UserIDNumber`.

**Note: I added spaces between columns on this question so it's easier to see and view what I am talking about. The files have no spaces...**

`test1.csv`:

```
"SamAccountName","LoginNumber","Type,"ContractorDomain","ExpirationDateFromAd"
"jd12395"       ,"0031482"    ,"H"  ,"P12345"          ,"2016/06/26 13:59"
"jwet"          ,""           ,"P"  ,"A52671"          ,""
"x023js"        ,"0418230"    ,"P"  ,""                ,""
"1b3gas5"       ,"2167312"    ,"H"  ,"425126"          ,"2015/11/17 12:00"
"632g1fsa"      ,"0052142"    ,"L"  ,""                ,""
"x023js"        ,"0720182"    ,"P"  ,""                ,"2016/06/26 13:59"
"4126hs"        ,""           ,"H"  ,""                ,"2016/08/12 4:32"
"axv"           ,"2058194"    ,"A"  ,"L21514"          ,"2016/03/11 7:31"
```

`test2.csv`:

```
UserIDNumber,AccountDescriptionDetails,ReportExpirationDate
0052142     ,Company CEO              ,
0418230     ,Software Developer       ,20161124
0031482     ,Software Developer       ,
2167312     ,Project Manager          ,20151117
0720182     ,QA Tester                ,20160128
1840237     ,Accountant Administrator ,
0000418     ,Program Manager          ,20160309
```

The end result of test1.csv should look like this:

```
"SamAccountName","LoginNumber","Type,"ContractorDomain","ExpirationDateFromAd","ExpirationDateFromReport"
"jd12395"       ,"0031482"    ,"H"  ,"P12345"          ,"2016/06/26 13:59"    ,""
"jwet"          ,""           ,"P"  ,"A52671"          ,""                    ,""
"x023js"        ,"0418230"    ,"P"  ,""                ,""                    ,"20161124"
"1b3gas5"       ,"2167312"    ,"H"  ,"425126"          ,"2015/11/17 12:00"    ,"20151117"
"632g1fsa"      ,"0052142"    ,"L"  ,""                ,""                    ,""
"x023js"        ,"0720182"    ,"P"  ,""                ,"2016/06/26 13:59"    ,"20160128"
"4126hs"        ,""           ,"H"  ,""                ,"2016/08/12 4:32"     ,""
"axv"           ,"2058194"    ,"A"  ,"L21514"          ,"2016/03/11 7:31"     ,""
```

## what I have tried so far...

```
$logins = Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\test1.csv' |
          Select-Object -Expand LoginNumber

$accountStatus = @{}
Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\test2.csv' | Where-Object {
  $logins -contains $_.UserIDNumber
} | ForEach-Object {
  $accountStatus[$_.AccountDescriptionDetails] = $_.ReportExpirationDate
}

(Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\test1.csv') |
  Select-Object -Property *, @{n='ExpirationDateFromReport';e={
    if ($accountStatus.ContainsKey($_.AccountDescriptionDetails)) {
      $accountStatus[$_.AccountDescriptionDetails]
    } else {
      'User Match Not Found'
    }
  }} | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\final.csv' -NoType
```

For some reason, all the values of the appended column are blank.

Comment: You have 2 records with empty login number in `test1.csv`. How do you want to handle them? Also, `AccountDescriptionDetails` in `test2.csv` isn't unique, so you can't use it as the key in a hashtable. The values in the `UserIDNumber` column also aren't unique, sou you can't use that as a key either. How do you expect to get unique associations if you don't have unique attributes?

Comment: if there is no `LoginNumber` in test1.csv, then the value for `ExpirationDateFromReport` should be `User Not Found`. In addition, if the `LoginNumber` is not in test2.csv, in the file test1.csv, then the value for `ExpirationDateFromReport` should still be `User Not Found`.

Comment: What if there are two (or more) lines for a given user ID in `test2.csv`?

Comment: There should be no duplicated `UserIDNumber` in test2.csv. Also there will be no blank values for `UserIDNumber` in test2.csv. They are all unique in test2.csv

Comment: Well, there are. At least in your example. Sample data that doesn't reflect your actual data is useless.

Comment: yes, the logic matches what is in my actual data (which I cannot give here).

Comment: also just an fyi, test1.csv is about 80k lines. test2.csv is about 400k lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97791/discussion-between-fiddle-freak-and-ansgar-wiechers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account descriptions are not unique and also don't exist in `test1.csv`, so they won't work as keys for the hashtable. The user IDs would work, though.

```
$accountStatus = @{}
Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\test2.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  $accountStatus[$_.UserIDNumber] = $_.ReportExpirationDate
}
```

Use an `if` statement for handling empty report expiration dates:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\test2.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  $accountStatus[$_.UserIDNumber] = if ($_.ReportExpirationDate) {
    $_.ReportExpirationDate
  } else {
    'No Date Found'
  }
}
```

Then add the new column to `test1.csv`:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\Temp\test1.csv' |
  Select-Object -Property *, @{n='ExpirationDateFromReport';e={
    if ($accountStatus.ContainsKey($_.LoginNumber)) {
      $accountStatus[$_.LoginNumber]
    } else {
      'User Match Not Found'
    }
  }} | Export-Csv 'C:\Temp\final.csv' -NoType
```